# iOS 6 rotation to Portrait Upside Down does not work for UITableViewController, iOS 5 is fine

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have an app that supports all four orientations which works fine on **iOS 5**.

However, on **iOS 6**, all of my **UIViewController** classes rotate properly, but my **UITableViewController** classes do not rotate to **PortraitUpsideDown**.

The supported orientations for the app includes all four options.

The AppDelegate supports all orientations:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    //return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

All of my view classes implement the necessary methods, including those introduced for iOS 6:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    BOOL bReturn = [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
    return (bReturn);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (YES);
}
```

The only difference I can find is the way the views are displayed.

**UIViewController**

```
InfoViewController *infoController = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentModalViewController:infoController animated:YES];
```

**UITableViewController**

```
MenuViewController *menuController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuController];
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Not entirely sure what affect the implementation would have on the rotation, and even less sure of what to do about it.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm, just occurred to me that I am presenting a UINavigationController, and not my MenuViewController object. Not sure if this is the actual issue, or how to associate supported orientations with the UINavigationController object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comment I made above, I created a new class that inherits from **UINavigationController** and added the method to identify the supported orientations.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    //return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Then when I need to **presentModalViewController** for a **UITableViewController**, I create  an object of my new **RotationNavigationController** class.

Seems to have solved all my problems.

Comment: This is such a time-saving answer. It does indeed work. I had this problem for days. Thank you so much for sharing your answer with us.

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
            if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
                return  UIInterfaceOrientationMask(rawValue: UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue | UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue)
            } else {
                return .All
            }
    }
```